# Why do different ways of calling Raku result in very different startup times?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I have `v2020.12` of Rakudo installed on my computer and have also built `v2020.12` from source.  When profiling startup times, I noticed the following results: (these benchmarks use [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine), but I also got similar results with `time`).

```sh
$ which raku
/opt/rakudo-pkg/bin/raku
$ /opt/rakudo-pkg/bin/raku --version
Welcome to Rakudo(tm) v2020.12.
Implementing the Raku(tm) programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.12.
$ /opt/rakudo-pkg/bin/raku ~/.raku/bin/red --help > /dev/null # make sure modules are compiled
$ hyperfine -i '/opt/rakudo-pkg/bin/raku /home/dsock/.raku/bin/red'
Benchmark #1: /opt/rakudo-pkg/bin/raku /home/dsock/.raku/bin/red
  Time (mean ± σ):     890.0 ms ±  15.5 ms    [User: 1.411 s, System: 0.068 s]
  Range (min … max):   861.3 ms … 913.4 ms    10 runs

  Warning: Ignoring non-zero exit code.

$ ~/forks/rakudo-clean/install/bin/raku --version
Welcome to Rakudo(tm) v2020.12.
Implementing the Raku(tm) programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.12.
$ ~/forks/rakudo-clean/install/bin/raku ~/.raku/bin/red --help > /dev/null # compile modules 
$ hyperfine -i '~/forks/rakudo-clean/install/bin/raku /home/dsock/.raku/bin/red'
Benchmark #1: ~/forks/rakudo-clean/install/bin/raku /home/dsock/.raku/bin/red
  Time (mean ± σ):     343.9 ms ±   7.9 ms    [User: 461.3 ms, System: 43.9 ms]
  Range (min … max):   328.1 ms … 355.9 ms    10 runs

  Warning: Ignoring non-zero exit code.
```

As you can see, `red --help` took ~3× as long to execute when I used the version of raku installed in `/opt`.  This isn't an issue specific to `red` – I also tested with `zef --help` and observed a similar issue.  Interestingly, the issue did *not* occur if I ran the `/opt` copy of raku from inside the `~/forks/rakudo-clean/` directory.

This last point leads me to wonder whether the underling issue is somehow related to `$PATH` searches or something similar.  (Maybe something like the [difficulty Ruby has with `$LOAD_PATH`](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap#path-pre-scanning)?)

A few alternatives:

1. I have somehow misconfigured my raku install in a way that causes this slowdown, but people who installed raku correctly don't run into this issue (this possibility is why this is a question on SO rather than being reported as a bug).
2. The default installation for raku causes this issue.  Everyone experiences it, but we can fix it by updating build/install instructions.
3. This is a bug in Rakudo that needs to be fixed at that level rather than through installation configuration.
4. Something else/I'm more deeply confused.

I appreciate any help you can provide, including just letting me know if you also see the same large difference in start times.  Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I did a bit more digging,and discovered the `RAKUDO_MODULE_DEBUG` environmental variable.  After setting that, I discovered some more info – specifically, in the slower version (`/opt/rakudo-pkg/bin/raku`), I have a number of lines like the following:

```sh
 1 RMD: Trying to load 77AFF4B677E65751FF5E96B6D6FA230222D29DFE.repo-id from /home/dsock/lib/.precomp
 1 RMD: Repo changed:
          9255FA5B5841CF5E09BDD37B3C43740099B4851F
          97741FE305502F0915F57D977BCFC518F958D4FC
        Need to re-check dependencies.
```

In contrast, loading the same dependecy with `~/forks/rakudo-clean/install/bin/raku` produced the following output (among much else, of course).

```
 1 RMD: Trying to load 77AFF4B677E65751FF5E96B6D6FA230222D29DFE.repo-id from /home/dsock/lib/.precomp
 1 RMD: dependency: FFEE376ADAD76513435BB73B169C73EC50B35567 home#sources/FFEE376ADAD76513435BB73B169C73EC50B35567 CAB0E9BB22A61F32FA98CFEA40EDFDD6E4495D06 CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:short-name<CX::Red::Bool>)
```

This *partly* answers my question: the `/opt` version launches more slowly because it is re-checking dependencies.  But this really just raises more questions.  Why is that version finding something different when it looks in the same folder?  Given that it is, why isn't it updating the cache properly so that it finds what it's looking for the next time it runs?

Comment: Are you using `-Ifoo` somewhere, possibly under the hood?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I'm not sure.  I certainly didn't _think_ so, and checking my `ENV` variables and grepping around a bit didn't show any obvious place where `-Ifoo` or similar could have been set.  But I could easily have missed something.  Your comment pointed me in the direction of the "module search path" (which is the term `raku --help` uses for the effect of `-I`, but doesn't seem to be used elsewhere in the docs.  Does that path go by another name?).  The result of all that was discovering a bit more info, as described in my edit.  But I'm not quite sure what to make of it.

Comment: Thing is that the directory pointed to by `-I` makes a SHA of all the files in there (and its subdirectories) to make sure all dependencies haven't changes since the last time a module that lives in there, got precompiled.  If you have a lot of files in there, it will get noticeable!

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I had no idea that's what it did internally but … definitely something I'm going to keep in mind

Comment: Note the directory pointed to by `-I` only makes a sha of all files / sub directories if it doesn't contain a META6.json file (i.e. `-Ilib`). `-I.` will only consider the files listed in the META6.json. As you noticed `bin/red` contains `use lib "lib";` which is arguably wrong for a distributed script (after it is installed why attempt to load some random "lib" directory in whatever cwd you happen to be in at the time). It would be slightly better for it to use `use lib ".";` but I wouldn't `use lib ...` period in any installable code (tests don't get installed so are a primary use for it).

Comment: I have a script to delete old precomp directories [delete-precomp.sh](https://gist.github.com/b2gills/a10731df08e28653c044ae3c1d46a749). I don't think that is your issue though. I think it is an `-I` or `use lib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later, I am no longer experiencing this issue (rakudo v2021.12).  Additionally, comments on the question (and a lack of answers/activity) suggest that others were never experiencing the same issue.

Thus, I'm concluding that whatever issue I experienced was an idiosyncratic configuration error on my part and considering this question resolved.